# How to remove icon space from TabView

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I need to remove the icon space from and the space between the text and the top of a Tab in a TabHost? I just want to display the text.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
`<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>`
```

This is the theme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#0767de</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar1</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="LightTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <!-- set textColor to red, so you can verify that it applied. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#0767de</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

This is the Java file

```
 /**Tab All**/
    intent=new Intent(this,tab_all.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator((View)findViewById(R.id.tab_all)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    /**Tab Today**/
    intent=new Intent(this,tab_today.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator((View)findViewById(R.id.tab_all)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    /**Tab This Month**/
    intent=new Intent(this,tab_thismonth.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator((View)findViewById(R.id.tab_all)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Now it is like this.
[image]

But I need to convert it to something like this.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Replace this in your Tabhost, LinearLayout and FrameLayout!

I think the parent's view has a larger height, so your tabhost just takes on it's parent's height

Comment: It doesn't work. It creates this space because of the android default TabHost layout. I need to remove it.